# How to pass multiple params in a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Im making some filters, and I have a form that searches with multiple params.

I want to search products by `:category` and `:price` at the same time,
how can I make the query?

Im trying:

```
@pins = Pin.where('category CONTAINS ?', params[:category] && 'min_price BETWEEN ? AND ?', params[:pin][:min_value], params[:pin][:max_value])
```

But It won't work!

Answer (score 2):

```
@pins = Pin.where('category LIKE ? and min_price BETWEEN ? AND ?',
                  params[:category], params[:pin][:min_value], 
                  params[:pin][:max_value])
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm getting this error:PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONTAINS"

Comment: Ok I changed CONTAINS for LIKE and it worked. Thanks